# Code Verification done by CLR in .NET

Tags: c#

I am reading CLR via C# and as part of IL and Verification section the following is mentioned.

> "While compiling IL into native instructions, the CLR performs a
>   process called Verification. Verificaiton examines the high level IL
>   Code and ensures that everything the code does is safe. For example,
>   verification checks that every method is called with the correct
>   number of parameters, that each parameter passed to every method is of
>   the correct type....."

My Questions are the below:

> 1. The C# compiler itself checks that the functions are passed with the correct number and type of parameters. Then what does this
>      verification mean.
> 2. Does this mean the runtime type identification of objects is done as part of this process, specifically the is/as cast operations.

Can anyone throw light into this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The C# compiler itself checks that the functions are passed with the correct number and type of parameters. Then what does this verification mean.

Think of the C# compiler as a mere front-end to the CLR (one of many possible such front-ends). The CLR cannot delegate IL code verification responsibility to anyone else (earlier in the process), because it otherwise couldn't be sure the IL code were safe. There isn't any other reliable force preventing at attacked standing between the compiler (its output) and the CLR from modifying the IL code the compiler has produced.

> Does this mean the runtime type identification of objects is done as part of this process, specifically the is/as cast operations.

To further comment on the `is`/`as` portion of your question: run-time type identification is done on *run-time*. IL verification happens at a moment I would name as *“just-in-time compile-time”*. Hence no, `is`/`as` is evaluated later—when *actually* executed.

Comment: +1 For the *just-in-time compile-time*; great way to distinguished them.

Answer (score 2):

While the C# compiler verifies argument type safety when compiling C# code into IL code, the verification process is a similar step when converting IL to native code, done by the CLR through the just-in-time (JIT) compiler.

I believe this is done as a measure of security, where an attacker could modify the IL code before it has been compiled by the CLR, like in [this example](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Full_Trust_CLR_Verification_issue%3a_changing_the_return_address_order).

The type verification of the sort you mention happens during run-time execution, after the IL code has been compile into native code by the JIT.

There is a very helpful diagram under [the CLR article in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) that clearly shows this distinction and the differences between the two compilation times and later execution.